# what kind of problems can lack of deallocation cause?

Tags: memory-leaks, fortran, glibc, memory-management

i am currently experiencing a problem were i get

`*** glibc detected *** ./efit: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000006127f0 ***`

with the usual memory map and backtrace information that comes with a `glibc` error. i am, however, unable to find the cause of this problem. it seems like (basically) my entire program is finished by the time this happens. one thing i read online is that this could be due to lack of deallocation.

now, i have been running the program without deallocating a few of my arrays (i was under the impression that deallocation can cause memory leaks but that this will only affect the performance and efficiency of the program while it runs). now, when i start the program fresh, i am running into this error.

is it possible that my previous executions of the program without deallocating my arrays is 'coming back to haunt me' in the sense that there is unfree memory from previous executions which i am trying to write to?

if not i am completely confused by this error. any clues on where i should begin to look and/or how i should debug to find it?

for what it is worth, i am using gfortran to compile

EDIT:
while the compilation options did not directly identify this problem at first, it helped me to whittle it away. i was using an integer variable `iat` for `iat=1,natoms` in a `do` loop, and then a few lines later, thought `iat` was describing a different integer within the bounds of `1,natoms`. i was referencing an array outside the bounds of the array. when i corrected a few of the warnings listed by your compilation options, this error turned into a much clearer description of the error: `Fortran runtime error: Index '7' of dimension 1 of array 'isnormed' above upper bound of 6`.

What was it that kept this error from being produced the first time? the only reach changes i made which the compilation warnings told me about were changing `read(fout, '(a)'), line100' to`read(fout, '(a)') line100' (removing the comma) and changing old style character descriptions `character*100 line100` to newer `character(100) line100` descriptions.

Comment: Some of the warnings/errors that you describe are compile time warnings.  They are identified by the compiler when you compile your source code.  The "above upper bound" error is a runtime error -- it didn't occur until you ran your program.  That is why it didn't appear in the first group of warnings/errors.   The runtime checks aren't a default because they have a CPU time cost but are very helpful while developing a program.

Comment: i'm aware of that, my question is that i was getting a runtime error BEFORE i made those compile time changes, but i never got the "above upper bound" error - i simply got a `glibc detected` error. my question is why making those simple compile time warning changes turned the `glibc detected` error into a "above upper bound" error.

Comment: I can't explain that, unless you didn't have the -fcheck=all option at first.

Comment: well, i didn't, but as you said, all of those options are compile time checking. none of them are runtime error checking options, correct? the weird thing is that after i changed the simple warnings it gave me , i got the "above upper bound" error instead of `glibc`. as i told my wife ... it was as if i painted over a scratch in the wall and it somehow magically fixed the door!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error from a  previous run of your program cannot effect the next run.  The OS loads a new version of the executable and provides it with memory.  Only if you have the program write out info to a file and read it in on the next run can their be transfer of information.

Memory is automatically deallocated by the OS when the program finishes.  Additionally, for Fortran >=95, allocatable arrays that are local to a procedure are automatically deallocated by Fortran when the procedure returns.

Most likely you have a memory usage problem that is corrupting the internal structures that describe memory that is used by your program.   With Fortran this is possible by having argument mismatched between caller and callee, by indexing past the end of an array, or with pointers.   Are you using pointers?  If not, the first two are typically easy to guard against in this era.  Place your procedures into modules and "use" those modules.  This will allow the compiler to check argument consistency.  Compile with the option for run-time checking of subscripts.   This will find out if you are indexing past the end of an array and storing in other memory.

With gfortran, try the following compiler options: -O2  -fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fwhole-file  -fcheck=all  -std=f2008  -pedantic  -fbacktrace.   If some of these identify too many warnings, the important one for this issue is fcheck=all, or even narrower, fcheck=bounds.

Answer (score 1):

This message is not about failure to deallocate. It's saying the heap is corrupt. There are many ways this can occur, but forgetting to free an array is not one of them.  Must likely if this is Fortran code is an array incorrectly declared.

The message is being generated when `glibc` does a consistency check.  So *when* the message occurs (beginning or end of the run) is not relevant except that you know the corruption occurred at some time (but could be any time) before the message appeared.

A corrupt heap means that the answers your program is generating may be anything from perfectly correct to completelyl useless.  You'll have to get rid of this message.

> (i was under the impression that deallocation can cause memory leaks but that this will only affect the performance and efficiency of the program while it runs

This is backward.  Memory leaks occur when deallocation is *not* done.

The best way forward is to use a tool like `valgrind` designed to detect and report heap problems in detail.

Comment: thanks, this is what i meant - that *lack* of deallocation can cause memory leaks. for what it is worth, am i correct that memory leaks only affect a running program and once it is terminated, it is no longer a problem?

Comment: A memory leak is just what it sound like.  The machine has a fixed amount of memory. If you have a leak, the O/S and runtime system think chunks of memory are allocated when in fact you're not using them.  This means your program is consuming memory resource it doesn't need.  The result can be anything from benign (using 20K instead of 10K bytes will be totally unnoticable on a modern workstation) to a disaster (using 8Gb instead of 2Gb on a 4Gb machine).