# Fortran - Index of matrix out of bounds

Tags: matrix, fortran

I'm coding in Fortran via Ubuntu and use a make file to run the compiler - bit of a novice when it comes down to compilers, but I think there lies the problem. I've done some research and my problem is identical to that asked here: [Index of matrix out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553258/index-of-matrix-out-of-range) . However in my case the -C (check bounds) flag has always been on and I'm only recently experiencing this problem. I haven't changed the compiler at all so very confused. So for example I write:

```fortran
  REAL, ALLOCATABLE   :: mat_b(:,:)
  INTEGER             :: i

  ALLOCATE(mat_b(5,5))
  mat_b = 0.0
  DO i = -1, 10
        WRITE(*,*) mat_b(i,:)
  END DO

  WRITE(*,*) 100000*mat_b(6,:)
```

Its happy to write the first one:

```
     -0.98799251802048516        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000     
  4.43497120311741914E-312   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000     
   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000     
   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000     
   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000     
   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000     
   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000     
   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000       1.05365618368981430E-312
   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000      -4.64431912125404020E-042
   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000       0.13957067792614544     
   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000       3.60739284562909423E-313
   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000       7.03660474880717784E-002
```

but does complain about the second write statement saying its "outside of expected range (1:5)" Any idea why its not pricking it up the first time? Many thanks.

Comment: gfortran 4.7 picks up the second but not the first.  The only difference is a variable versus a constant index... Peculiar.  ifort detects the first.

Comment: There is a compiler diagnostic comparison at [Polyhedron](http://www.polyhedron.com/pb05-linux-diagnose0html). Please note the used compiler flags at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

It is important that you raise this as a bug in [gfortran bugzilla](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/).  You will get an email when it is fixed and you can then download the latest version.

It looks like it ignores the bounds-check flag when no arithmetic is done in a print statement.  If the last print statement had read

```
write(*,*) mat_b(6:)
```

It would not have triggered the bounds-check.  Since we now know that it checks bounds when there is arithmetic in a print statement, we could either wait for the fix or perform a simple low cost arithmetic function in the print loop.  For example, the print statement could be recoded as

```
write(*,*) 0+mat_b(i:)
```

That will cause it to fall over when there is a bounds-check violation.